# How to handle good answers with extra info for OP that isn't inherently relevant to the question

Tags: discussion

**EDIT -- Clarifying because of multiple votes to close as unclear**

***Is it a good thing or a bad thing to include extra bonus info in an answer that does not directly go toward answering the question posed?***

This would be bonus info that is either not-likely relevant and/or not inherently relevant to those with the same question as OP. Examples would be instructing OP on "best practice", correcting terminology mistakes, etc. in cases where those errors did not cause or aren't relevant to the posed issue.

If they ARE relevant then it makes sense to include -- *this is not what I'm talking about.* Example: if OP would have avoided the posed issue had they followed a "best practice" then talk about that "best practice".

---

**ORIGNAL LONG WINDED QUESTION**

**(1) How to treat info relevant to author but not the question?**
Is there is a standard, community-accepted way to provide a question-asker important info/tips that is relevant to them, yet not directly relevant to the question (and in turn, not relevant to users that have the same question)?

Here's an example to better illustrate what I mean:
[Polymer 1.0 Data Binding in <styles>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698302/polymer-1-0-data-binding-in-styles/30706761#30706761)

The answer to this question includes some "oh-and-by-the-way" info for the question-asker to let them know their structure is not in keeping with the latest recommendation from Polymer. That's important info for the question-asker who made that mistake or wasn't up to date, but it is not relevant to the question which asks how to bind styles. I've seen similar "notes-for-the-asker" in questions before, so I think there is a broader relevance outside the linked question as well.

Is there a "right" way to provide that info? My personal opinion is that it shouldn't take up real estate in the answer and should be a given as a comment on the question plus there should be an appropriate edit to the original question -- in the example linked, the code in the question should be edited/updated to remain in-keeping with the Polymer recommendation.

**(2) Does editing out the extra info "tighten up" the answer and/or does it remove author intent?**

I ask because the suggested edit of removing that extraneous, "oh-and-by-the-way" info (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12715634) was rejected because it "deviates from the original intent". I'm curious what the community opinion is on this because I currently see it from both angles. Removing that extra info from the answer, in my opinion, makes the answer better in that it strictly sticks to answering the question posed. Nevertheless, the author chose to add that extra bit to the answer and while it's my opinion that it's only pertinent to the question-asker, perhaps the author felt differently -- is that the answerer's prerogative that should be protected?

Again, curious if the community has an official stance? And if there isn't, should there be?

Comment: There's a down-vote and vote to close with "unclear what you're asking". The question seems clear to me, but if it's not to others, please post a comment saying what's unclear and I'll edit/clarify.

Comment: Why do you want to remove "best practices" from a answer?  It may enlighten the OP and if others do not know about them then they do after reading the answer.

Comment: If it's extraneous info, I think the answer loses focus and it degrades the answer. We know with 100% certainty people are reading an answer because they are interested in the posed question. In the example given, people aren't reading an answer on how to bind Polymer styles in order to learn the Polymer recommended way to structure their code. The best practice rec in the answer becomes noise for poeple that just want to see the proposed question answered. If people want to learn "best practice" better to find a "best practice" Q or ask one themselves.

Answer (score 1):

> How to treat info relevant to author but not the question?

I'm not sure how you are going to decide that info provided is only relevant to the author. You might see an answer that elaborates beyond the scope of the question, hopefully because the OP knows the next pitfalls on the road to implementing their answer. Answers that really veer off-track and in the process bury the signal with noise it is time to down vote or leave a comment. It is a bit subjective and probably varies on context where the S/N cut-off point is.

> Does editing out the extra info "tighten up" the answer and/or does it remove author intent?

That removes author intent. If you're sure that the answer will be better when trimmed I would rather opt for suggesting to help out with editing in a comment before causing havoc. I assume answerers that write long posts and provide extra context know what they are doing. If it turns out that they only typed so much because they think reputation is based on character count it is time to take action.

Comment: Thanks for a real answer. I'd been working on the assumption that answers and, in particular, good answers are in a sense owned by the community and that reviewers accept/deny edits first on whether or not an answer is improved and second on whether or not intent is preserved. I think your recommendation to leave a request in the comments to trim the answer is a pretty good one.

Answer (score 0):

Bonus info is almost required on questions that are borderline [XY-problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Personally I believe most of questions that prompt for "bonus info" in answer (vs. just comments) are of this kind.

Editing it out is almost always wrong thing to do. Instead comment to author asking to clarify which part is essential and what should be converted into comment on the question. Consider to downvote if the answer is really hard to understand due to extra info mixed in.

---

Imaginary sample question:

> how to remove single quote from string like `"where bob='"+removeQuoteHere +''"`

Exact answer to the question would be something like

> `removeQuoteHere = removeQuoteHere.replace("'", "");`

But almost every person answering it would recognize SQL injection and add proper recommendation that clearly not related to the question as asked, but essentially required for valid SO answer.